# Javascript filter an array of objects by a property of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have an array of `userList` which include user basic information.

```
this.state = {
    userList: [
        { name:"Ann", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Cathy", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Peter", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Ben", number:123456789 },
    ],
    vips: [ 
        { username:"Ann", years:2018 },
        { username:"Peter", years:2019 },
};
```

How I can return of the `vips` from `userList`? `vips.username` equals to `userList.name`

```
vips_return: [
        { name:"Ann", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Peter", number:123456789 },
]
```

I tried using .filter and .includes but I am not sure how to deal with objects.

```
const vips_return = userList.filter((user)=>
    vips.includes(user.name)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
userList.filter(user => vips.find(vip => vip.username === user.name));
```

`find` returns `undefined` if the value cannot be found in the array, so those are filtered out.

If you do this a lot and/or have a large data set, you should build a set of names first:

```
const vipNames = new Set(vips.map(vip => vip.username));

userList.filter(user => vipNames.has(user.name));
```

Comment: I think your field in case of vip should be `username`

Comment: how can I get the value of type? after .find

Comment: @susuwatari: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `reduce` and get the users in `userList` which are also in `vips`

```js
const input = {
    userList: [
        { name:"Ann", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Cathy", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Peter", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Ben", number:123456789 },
    ],
    vips: [ 
        { username:"Ann", years:2018 },
        { username:"Peter", years:2019 },
    ]
};

console.log(input.userList.reduce((acc, val) => { 
  if(!!input.vips.find(vip => vip.username === val.name)) { 
    acc.push(val);
  } 
  return acc; 
}, []));
```

Considering that the length of `vips` should be lower than the one of `userList`, or at max the same (`vips` should be a subset of `userList`), maybe a better approach is to map over the vips and get back the corresponding user, like below:

```js
const input = {
    userList: [
        { name:"Ann", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Cathy", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Peter", number:123456789 },
        { name:"Ben", number:123456789 },
    ],
    vips: [ 
        { username:"Ann", years:2018 },
        { username:"Peter", years:2019 },
    ]
};

console.log(input.vips.map(vip => input.userList.find(user => user.name === vip.username)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Map` and get the wanted objects.

```js
var state = { userList: [{ name: "Ann", number: 123456789 }, { name: "Cathy", number: 123456789 }, { name: "Peter", number: 123456789 }, { name: "Ben", number: 123456789 }], vips: [{ username: "Ann", years: 2018 }, { username: "Peter", years: 2019 }] },
    user = new Map(state.userList.map(o => [o.name, o])),
    vips = state.vips.map(({ username }) => user.get(username));
    
console.log(vips);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or take a shorter approach with a double mapping

```js
var state = { userList: [{ name: "Ann", number: 123456789 }, { name: "Cathy", number: 123456789 }, { name: "Peter", number: 123456789 }, { name: "Ben", number: 123456789 }], vips: [{ username: "Ann", years: 2018 }, { username: "Peter", years: 2019 }] },
    vips = state.vips
        .map(({ username }) => username)
        .map(Map.prototype.get, new Map(state.userList.map(o => [o.name, o])));
    
console.log(vips);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```